# Is it possible to try DeveloperX orgs (DevHub) in Salesforce Enterprise Trial Edition?

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, developer, enterprise, trial

I was wondering if this is possible to try out without touching the real Production environment. It seems we cannot create APEX in Enterprise Trial.

[image]
It seems like they haven't allowed any developments in Trial orgs, couldn't find any related reference.

Is there a way to get this working, appreciate any thoughts/help. 
Thanks.

Comment: On a related note, it looks like you accidentally signed up for something that's not Enterprise Edition; even Enterprise Edition trials get Apex Code and other automations.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, yes you're correct. Even though I got entered Enterprise from [**here**](https://www.salesforce.com/au/editions-pricing/sales-cloud/) it seems to be creating a Professional edition for some reason. I had not double checked the edition in setup-->company information since I registered for a Enterprise Trial. Is there a way you can register for Trial enterprise directly if you know of. Many Thanks.

Comment: Try [this link](https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/freetrial-sales-ee.jsp).

Comment: No luck @sfdcfox, it still creates a Professional edition for me. I initially thought it's because I haven't verified the email, but I did which seems not the reason.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to contact Sales. They have an internal tool they can use to create any type of trial org (at least, they used to, you'll have to check).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are already using a Trial org and don't want to use your actual org then Sign up for Dev Hub trial org. It gives you 30 Day full trial so you can easily test this.

https://developer.salesforce.com/promotions/orgs/dx-signup

Comment: Thanks @Tushar Sharma, I do have, and it's working perfectly fine. Wanted to see how it works in Prod, because once you enabled this, you can't disable it.

Comment: @PasanEeriyagama As far as that's concerned, enabling Scratch Orgs is "harmless"; no users will see any new features until permission sets are created and added to users to give them access to the features. It's completely invisible to normal users.